# Django: collectstatic does not collect my app

Tags: django, python-3.x, iis

I am going to deploy on IIS so all the following commands were executed on Windows (Server2016)

This is the structure of my django project:

```
$ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\djangoProject
.
├── static
├── manage.py
├── websrv
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
└── djangoProject
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.p
```

I set `STATIC_ROOT` in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\djangoProject\djangoProject\settings.py` to:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/djangoProject/static'
```

and obviously my app name (`websrv`) was added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` too.

but when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, the result is that only `admin` folder is collected under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Alsatex\static` and there is no folder for my main app (`websrv`)

Comment: Can you run `python manage.py findstatic` to tell us if it is seeing your app ?

Comment: `python manage.py findstatic websrv` returns `No matching file found for 'websrv'.`

Comment: What is defined in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: I just added: `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Alsatex/websrv',
)`
and it does copy my websrv file to static folder but dump all of them directly in static folder (not under static\websrv)